# how to return value from a html to another html

Tags: javascript, function, variables

i'm having a problem about my program right now. i'm practicing a program in a html that would accept an ID, and i would like that ID to be paste in a `<div>` in my other html, using two separate javascript. here's the javascript code:

```
    $("#btnGetID").click( function() {
        ....
        ....
        window.open('project.html');//used to open the other html file to paste the ID
        pasteID($('#myID').text());//this is the function name with parameter.
    });
```

the function pasteID(par) was coded in the other .js file. here's the code:

```
   function pasteID(par){
      var p_id = pasteID(par);// this line displays an error "too much recursion" in firebug
      return (p_id);
   }

   $("#DisplayID").click( function() {
      $('#putID').attr("value", pasteID(par));
   }
```

what's is that error "too much recursion"? how can i make this program right without that error? i cannot think of anything that would display my ID in the other html. can please somebady help me.? please

Comment: I'm not sure if you can do this:  `$('#putID').attr("value", pasteID(par));`. I think you have to do this: `$('#putID').attr("value", function(){pasteID(par)});`

Comment: @Emco.. i did that now but it didn't show my ID. but thank you for your time and reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this problem is already solved by using a cookie. please refer to this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5467936/how-to-display-the-set-cookie-to-another-html-page-on-submit). and thanks to experimentX.
hope this can help to some people out there that have the same question/problem.

Answer (score 2):

#### Your function

```
function pasteID(par){
  var p_id = pasteID(par);// this line displays an error "too much recursion" in firebug
  return (p_id);
}
```

You are calling `pasteID()` again inside of itself. Recursive functions should have a condition where it will stop calling itself, otherwise it will continue until it hits a limit (for example, out of memory).

Because you have no condition to stop recursively calling the function, your stack overflows (or the error here is *too much recursion*).

Comment: ok, that's a very clear explanation for me, thank you. so how should i do that to paste my ID in the other html.?