# how to display the set cookie to another html page on submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

im practicing on creating a html using jquery cookies. i already know how to set, get, and delete cookies. one thing i don't know is how to display the set cookies on the next page.
i have this html ccodes:

```
    <FORM id = 'login' meth0d = 'post' action = 'Coutput.html' >            
        <input id = 'name' type = "text"  value = ''>           
        <input id="btnSet" type="submit" value="Go"/>
        <input id="btndelete" type="button" value="delete cookie"/>
    </form>
```

and i have this javascript code:

```
    $('form#login :submit').addClass('inputSubmitBtn').click(function(){
       if($('#name').val() == "" ){         
          $("#name").focus();
          alert('please input name');
          return false;
       }
       else{
          $.cookie("cookie_name", null);
          $.cookie('cookie_name', $('#name').val());
          alert('new cookie name' +$('#name').val()));
          $('#name').append($.cookie('cookie_name'));
       };           
    });
```

questions:

1. why is it that everytime i  used `$.cookie('cookie_name', $('#name').val(), { expires: null, path: '/', domain: 'cegi1.html', secure: true });`, my cookie os always set to null, though i set another one, it always returns null?
2. how can i display my newly set cookie in Coutput.html? (ex. name = luke, output in Coutput.html must be "welcome luke")

thanks for reading. please help..

Comment: you can access cookies on any page by just the regular way , the value before setting if it is going as null value , cookies are stored at the client side.

Comment: yes, i get it now. i just have to write another .js file where i can call the cookie and include it in my coutput. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that `<input id="btnSet" type="submit" value="Go"/>` is submitting form to the other page before evaluating  `$('form#login :submit').click(function()`. And also you have got error on `alert('new cookie name' +$('#name').val()));`. This should work.

```
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.cookie.js"></script>
<script>
$(function ()
{
    $("#btnSet").click(function(){
       if($('#name').val() == "" ){         
          $("#name").focus();
          alert('please input name');
          return false;
       }
       else{
          $.cookie("cookie_name", null);
          $.cookie('cookie_name', $('#name').val());
          alert('new cookie name' +$('#name').val());
          $('#name').append($.cookie('cookie_name'));
       };           
        window.location = $(this).parent('form').attr("action");
    });
})

</script>

 <form id = 'login' meth0d = 'post' action = 'Coutput.html' >            
        <input id ="name" type = "text"  value="">           
        <input id="btnSet" type="button" value="Go"/>
        <input id="btndelete" type="button" value="delete cookie"/>
 </form>
```

On my `Coutput.html` i have

```
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.cookie.js"></script>
<script>
    alert($.cookie("cookie_name") );
</script>
```

If you want to delete the cookie on window close, then use  `window.unload` event and on jquery perhap [this](http://api.jquery.com/unload/). And you can delete cookie by resetting it to null.

Comment: thank you...it works. one question. how can i display my name in my coutput.html? and also, i want to delete the set cookie everytime i close the page, how to do it? thanks a lot :)

Comment: that's was so nice of you. i already display my name on the other page...thank you so much... this is just what i need